# mysql.connector for python : Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Tags: python, mysql, flask

Working on a project, and I'm using MySQL for user database.

I have attempted to fix this issue by changing request.form to request.form.get, but to no avail.

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, session
app = Flask(__name__)
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  password="",
  database="jimblonium"
)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()


@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/login")
def login():
    return render_template ('login.html')

@app.route("/l", methods =['GET', 'POST'])
def passIt():
    username = request.form.get("username")
    password = request.form.get("password")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # return username
        if request.method == 'POST':
            mycursor.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = % s AND password = % s', (username, password, ))
            account = mycursor.fetchone()
            if account:
                return "done!"
```

Comment: No space between `%` and `s`. Also don't store plain text passwords ([alternative](https://jam-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/refs/server/task/m_generate_password_hash.html)).

Comment: @danblack Plaintext passwords are placeholder for now

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
myvar =  request.form["username"]
myvartwo = request.form["password"]
```

Comment: gives me TypeError: 'ImmutableMultiDict' object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your query, the placeholders are `%s`, and you are inserting an space with `% s`. You need to modify it to:

```
mycursor.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = %s AND password = %s', (username, password, ))
```